# Approach to use JasperServer with custom java web application?

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports, business-intelligence, jasperserver

I need to implement a BI and reporting module for a custom ERP system. ERP is built using Java/JSP, Spring3, Struts2, Hibernate3, & MySQL; while security stuff is managed by spring security.

As off my current findings, **one of the standard approach** to use jasperserver for my purpose would be:

- To setup jasperserver as simple installed application on my server
- Create & Manage the BI related stuff, dashboards and reporting there
- and use web-service/iFrame/SSO approach to embed the required reports
  and dashboard into my ERP screen(s).

My question is that, what if I get source code of jasperserver and add it to my ERP's workspace in Eclipse, as just another java project and *then try to use custom data source for under lying jasperserver; in order to power the reports from with-in my web-application*? Of course the reports & dashboard still needs to be designed in iReport or JasperDesigner, but for filling the data i'll use my own code.

Can this also solve the issue of managing 2 separate apps? Does JasperServer source code helps here? Is this feasible? or is this even some thing practically achievable in a given time period?

Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Ahsan: Have you able to integrate Jasper dashboard in to Java web application? If you have any resource reference, can you please share it.

Comment: were you able to access it from java web application ?
I am trying to do the same if you have any resource to share, that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasper Reports can also be used as a library and it works like any other Java library, by the way, you can get the library from here: https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library (note that it's also included on Jasper Server and iReports)